# Who receive fee when developing bitcoin wallet using bitcoinJ

Tags: bitcoinj

Hey I am new developer on android development. I have a question I searched the web and did not find answer.
I wish someone can make it clear to me. who receive fee while creating new wallet app using bitcoinJ library ?
Can I put my developer wallet address to be sent to my wallet or these fees are sent to bitcoinj ? It's not clear at all to me about who receive these fees.
Second question : Is there any way to put fee and send it to my wallet on every transaction using bitcoinj or any other libraries.
Thank you

Comment: Fee is taken by the minner's that proceed your transaction from sender to receiver

Comment: is that bitcoinJ or me if as implemented bitcoinj in my app. I need please more explanation about that. Who is the miner is it anonymous one

Comment: read this: https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf

Comment: bitcoinj is used to integrate with blockchain, for more info kindly visit bitcoinj mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bitcoinj, and https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/